# Need to add employee search function in googlesite

Tags: python, flask, google-api

I have google sheet which stores all employee details (name, email, employee number, etc.) and I need a suggestion for creating a local web with Flask/Django, add search function and then upload it to google site intranet. I'm python user but never do something like this before

This is for all employee, I need to add something in googlesite like an employee search function. So everyone in the company can find colleagues email, name, etc. via google site

I dont have any code yet, but I think I can use Flask for Backend and ReactJS for Frontend design. I don't have the database and don't want anyone to add the employee data. So I gonna update the data via google sheet and need to retrieve the data from it

the step I thinking about is
1. we normally update the data via google sheet 
2. create a webpage with search function (which retrieve the data from google sheet) and maybe we use 127.0.0.5000 first
3. then use google API / Heroku to deploy 
4. embed URL in the google site
5. when employee go to this webpage, they can search name, email, etc. from here and shows the employee result

I learn some on the web and did something like this but I don't know how to adjust and link with the google sheet as the database instead of using SQLAlchemy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Sheet as your back-end database, you would require to implement [Google Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) in your web application. 
You may also require to generate App ID and Secret Key for authentication from [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)